# OSX 10.9.5 automount AFP network volume?

Tags: macos, afp, automount

I'm having problems getting automount to mount an AFP share at startup.

If I, as a non-root user, issue the following command from my terminal:

```
mount -t afp afp://user:pass@server/share-name ./share-mount-point
```

It works fine, and I can interact with the files.

I'm trying to do the same with automount.  I've added the following to auto_master, and created auto_afp:

/etc/auto_master:

```
 /my/global/mount/point auto_afp
```

/etc/auto_afp:

```
 /my/global/mount/point -fstype=afp afp://user:pass@server/share-name
```

This fails.  I see that `/my/global/mount/point` is created by root, in group wheel, but is empty.

When I run `sudo automount -vc`, the same thing happens.  I get output like `automount: /my/global/mount/point updated` but there's no AFP share mounted there.

I'm not even sure where to start debugging here.

Comment: This actually is a valuable addition to the questions/answers on this site (and it documents a trap other users might run into as well). So if you don't mind we would like to keep the question around for future visitors. If you don't agree, just delete it again and we will respect that with no bad feelings.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I figured it out.  The keys in the `auto_afp` file are paths that are relative to the path specified in the top-level `auto_master` file.

So if your `/etc/auto_master` has: `my/global/mount auto_afp`

Then your `/etc/auto_afp` should have: `point -fstype=....`

Finally to get visibility into what `automountd` is doing, add `AUTOMOUNTD_TRACE=2` to `/etc/autofs.conf`, watch `/var/log/system.log` with `tail -f`, and start navigating around your mount points.